# C# Xpath Query to find a single Node

Tags: c#, xpath

I want to find a simple element (Name) in an XML :

```
<ZoneContentMapping>  
 <ZoneContent> 
   <ContentId>72503</ContentId>  
   <StorefrontZoneId>Name</StorefrontZoneId>  
   <Type>ContentZone</Type>  
 </ZoneContent>
</ZoneContentMapping>
```

I am doing :

```
XmlNodeList objNode =  
objXML.SelectNodes("ZoneContentMapping/ZoneContent[ContentId='72503']/StorefrontZoneId");
```

my Node count is always zero, where am I going wrong ?

Comment: can you show the code that initialize objXML ?

Comment: What is `objXML` in your code sample? Please show its type, and also how you load the above sample XML into it.

Comment: I XmlDocument.LoadXml()'d that snippet in, ran the SelectNodes XPath and I got the single node that you were looking for.  Is it part of a bigger document or something?

Comment: This would work if StorefrontZoneId was a child of ContentId, but it is not.

Comment: I added an answer below, using axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are namespaces involved? I had a similar problem parsing Amazon AWS results, which turned out to be that I wasn't providing an XmlNamespaceManager with AWS namespace specified.

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(m_xml.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("amzn", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/");

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//amzn:Contents", mgr);
```

The namespace prefix is arbitrary, but seems to be necessary in the XPath even though no namespace prefix is used in the XML itself. I couldn't find a way to tell it to associate an empty namespace prefix with the specified namespace URL.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath looks good, so does the XML. Tried it in XmlSpy and I get "Name" so it should work. However, try to add an additional slash at the beginning just in case...

```
XmlNodeList objNode = objXML.SelectNodes ("/ZoneContentMapping/ZoneContent[ContentId='72503']/StorefrontZoneId");
```

Or try [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) instead...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the *context* in which you are executing your query. If you load the document in the XPath engine I use here, the root context is the only node provided, `ZoneContentMapping`. Remember that your query:

```
ZoneContentMapping/...
```

Expands to:

```
child::ZoneContentMapping/...
```

As the default axis in XPath is `child`. So your query is probably looking for a child of ZoneContentMapping called ZoneContentMapping. Oops.

Try:

```
self::ZoneContentMapping/ZoneContent[ContentId='72503']/StorefrontZoneId
```

You can also prepend a `/` to the query, which does the search from the root of the XML document, regardless of your current context.

Comment: In normal circumstances, the default context is the _document node_ of the document, which will become root (`/`) in XPath, not the root node.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath works:

ZoneContentMapping/ZoneContent/StorefrontZoneId[preceding-sibling::ContentId='72503']

and here is a good resource:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/print.php/c7589__1/

Comment: And your XPath is semantically different from his how? Hint: the "non-working" XPath in the question does not in any way assume that "StorefrontZoneId was a child of ContentId".

Comment: It's very different! Plus, I used his xml and applied the xpath to it, and got the value 'name' as was requested. The only thing I did different was use XmlNode as the type instead of XmlNodeList

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way you could go about it if you'd like:

```
        string XmlFilePath = @"C:\blablabla"; 

        XmlDocument LoadXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        LoadXmlDoc.Load(XmlFilePath);

        XmlNodeList YourNodeList = LoadXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("StorefrontZoneId");

        LoadXmlDoc.Save(XmlFilePath);
```